# How to upload file on remote machine to Amazon s3 from Jenkins

Tags: javascript, node.js, protractor, cucumber

I'm running my Protractor browser test remotely to a VM from Jenkins. How can I upload the file I downloaded on the remote machine to Amazon s3 when the location I set for the default_directory is in the same repository of the project but downloaded file got saved remote machine download folder?

```
var downloadsPath = path.resolve(__dirname, '../e2e/downloads');
multiCapabilities:
[{
    'browserName': 'chrome',
    specs: 'features/*.feature',
    'chromeOptions': {
        prefs: {
            download: {
                'prompt_for_download': false,
                'directory_upgrade': true,
                'default_directory': downloadsPath
            }
        }
    }
}],
```

In my spec file:

```
const downloadDirectory = './e2e/downloads';
fs.readdir(downloadDirectory, async (err, files) => {
            if (err) throw err;
            return await Promise.all(files.map(file => {

                var s3 = new AWS.S3();
                var putObjectPromise = s3.putObject({
                    Bucket: 'reports',
                    Key: file,
                    Body: fs.createReadStream(path.join(downloadDirectory, '/' , file)),
                    ACL: 'public-read'
                }).promise();

                return putObjectPromise.then(function(data) {

                    return Promise.resolve(true);
                }).catch(function(err) {

                    return Promise.reject(err);
                });
            }));
        });
```

Comment: You can consider using the [pastebin](https://pastebin.com/) to transfer the files from remote machine to S3 bucket.

Comment: But this needs to be automated through protractor and how come the file is downloaded on the remote machine and not on JENKINS WORKSPACE